# Syntactic structure of “International Women’s Day”

Tags: possessives, noun-phrases

According to the general rule, in possessive phrases -‘s is placed right between the Possessor Phrase and the Thing-Possessed Phrase.

On the 8th of March one celebrates the International Day of Women. *International* is clearly dependent on *Day*, not on *Women*, so, figuratively speaking, *international day* is the Thing-Possessed Phrase, and *Women* is the Possessor Phrase.

How come we say *International Women’s Day* instead of *Women’s International Day*?

Comment: I'd say it's a proper name consisting of the genitive NP "Women's day" modified by the adjective "International".

Comment: Traditionally “Women’s Day” is analyzed as a Determiner Phrase headed by the Possessive Suffix, not as an NP. 
So, -‘s here serves as a determiner that is the head of the entire phrase together with the adjective. That is why we do not use the article in the beginning.

Comment: I'd say that the genitive "Women's Day" is an NP with "day" as head and "women's" as genitive NP. This we have one NP functioning in the structure of another. Some might say that the genitive NP is a subject-determiner, but that doesn't mean that "women's is not an NP since it has an NP as head.

Comment: @BillJ, thank you! That’s exactly how I see it now, and it does make sense.

Answer (score 3):

"Day of Women" and "Women's Day" are equivalent, and form noun phrases. "International" is an adjective describing the scope of the entire noun phrase, not of its parts.

Comment: One could even argue that 'International Women's Day' is non-analysable into individual elements, a lexeme in its own right. Neither [International] [Women's Day] (the particular Woman's Day that has international scope) nor [International Women's] [Day] nor [International] [Women's] [Day]: a compound proper noun not submitting to analysis beyond sounding reasonably constituted. Compare 'Beware He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named/Beware He Who Must Not Be Named' (both variants can be found used). No 'Him'. And 'Cloud Cuckoo Land'.

Comment: It is written as separate words, thus it's a syntactic construction, not a compound.

Comment: It's a proper name and proper names generally aren't syntactically analyzable, even if they may resemble ordinary noun phrases.

Answer (score 1):

"Women’s Day" is  called a *superordinate noun phrase*; "women's" is the *genitive noun phrase* . "day" is the *head*. The *possessive genitive* "women's" fills the role of a *determiner* such as "the"; it is not to be confused with "women's"  in "women's university" (descriptive genitive), where "women's" is a modifier.

This construction is considered to be a noun phrase embedded as a definite determinative in another noun phrase.

The adjective "international" is a premodifier of the superordinate noun phrase.

(Facts taken from *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* , Quirk et al., § **5.121**)

The fact that this genitive is of the possessive sort rather than of the descriptive sort results from some reasoning: the day has nothing in itself that is particular to women, and it is merely being dedicated to them; a women's university, on the contrary is conceived to suit women rather than men.

It seems that "International Women’s Day" is used instead of "Women’s International Day" because this latter usage would presuppose that there are other days dedicated to women (perhaps a "national day", or an "equality day", or other), and also the idea of an *international day  dedicated to women* is not that of a *day dedicated to women internationally*, which is what we tend to read in the initial construction.

Comment: I would rather consider “women’s” as a descriptive genitive here, which functions as an adjective modifying “day”. So we have: [null article] + [adj. women’s] + [head noun “day”].

Comment: @Alessandro Women's  day itself is just as any other day; it harbours certain special manifestations that have to do with political matters concerning women, but that is true for other days in the year, and that is no reason to call those a women's day; on the other hand, a women's university is not as any other university: for instance, it is a place where you find only women, and then the lavatories are more likely to be lavatories only for women.